# Extracting the Argument of a Complex Exponential

Tags: functions, complex, expression-manipulation

Let's say I have a complex exponential `A*Exp[I*B]`, and I want to find `B`. The obvious way is to use the `Arg[]` function, but it only gives you values between `-Pi` and `+Pi`. Is there any way I can extract `B` even if it's not within this range?

Comment: I believe that this question is not well-defined. You can always shift $B$ by integer multiples of $2\pi$ without changing $A \exp(i B)$.

Answer (score 2):

I would use something like the following

```
A Exp[I B];

Cases[%, Exp[u_] :> Cancel[u/I], ∞] // First
(* B *)
```

Comment: Very useful answer thanks!
I made it into a function like this (obvious for the most)
GetArg[x_]:=Cases[{x}, Exp[u_] :> Cancel[u/I], ∞] // First;